# How do I pad a QString with spaces?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How can I pad a QString with spaces on the end?

For example, I want a QString to be 4 characters in total, and it's only 1 character long.  I would like the last 3 to be spaces.

Comment: `QString foo( "1" ); foo += QString( 3, ' ' );`

Comment: As a more general answer (and without resorting to just saying RTFM), if you look in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/) under the [QString](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html) [class reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/classes.html) and do a search on the text "pad" the [function below](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html#leftJustified) is found.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Strangely enough, there's a function for specifically that called `QString::leftJustified`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#leftJustified

So `paddedString = originalString.leftJustified(4, ' ');` would do the trick.

*(Note that you can also optionally truncate the string if it's longer than your character limit by passing in a third parameter of `true`.)*

Comment: `originalString.resize(4, ' ')` will also do the trick

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [QString::arg()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg) overload which take a field width parameter. The field width value is the total number of desired characters, not the padding size. You need to use a negative field width value for left padding, a positive for right padding

```
QString QString::arg(const QString & a, 
        int fieldWidth = 0, const QChar & fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' ))
```

Most useful in a `printf` style formatting, for instance.

```
QString("%1: %2 - %3").arg("a", -4).arg(2).arg(10);
```

gives `"a   :2 - 10"`